# How can you find a 3-digit number "ABC", such that (ABC)/N = AxBxC ? Here, N=4.

Tags: number-theory, artificial-intelligence

How can you find a 3-digit number "ABC", such that (ABC)/N = AxBxC ?
Here, N=4.
Like, if abc/7= axbxc,  answer is 735

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Analytically, $~100a+10b+c = nabc~$ yields   $~~[1]~~  10b+c=a(nbc−100)$   $~~[2]~~  100a+c=b(nac−10)$   $~~[3]~~  10(10a+b)=100a+10b=c(nab−1).$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a general solution for arbitrary $N$ to your question, but you can write a simple code to check this (for example in python):

```
N = 4
for a in range(1, 10):
    for b in range(10):
        for c in range(10):
            if 100*a + 10*b + c == N * a * b * c:
                print(100*a + 10*b + c)
```

Output:

```
384
```

Comment: Thanks. In my case N is 4. Can you describe the algorithm in short? If you can it will be helpfull for me.

Comment: It just runs through all possible digits of 3-digit numbers ($a\in\{1,..,9\}$, $b\in\{0,..,9\}$, $c\in\{0,..,9\}$) and if theabove property holds ($"abc"=100*a+10*b+c == N*a*b*c$), then it prints out the number.

Comment: Well described. By the way, why a∈{1,..,9} , but b&c∈{0,..,9} ) ?

Comment: If $a=0$, you don't really have a 3-digit number.

Comment: oh. Got it. Thanks man. Have a great time!

Comment: You might want to use range(1,10) and range(10)

Comment: Thanks for the note Arthur.